# RegEx filter to merge different urls (PhpBB)

Tags: google-analytics

I have a phpBB forum and I want to merge the different urls Google Analytics throws up into 1, eg:

```
 /forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=6457
 /forum/viewtopic.php?t=6457
 /forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=6457&start=40
```

I'd like them all to point to

`/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6457`

I devised the following regEx filter:

Search and replace
  -> filter field: Request URI

Search string: `\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?f=([0-9]*)&t=[0-9]`

Replace string: `\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?t=([0-9]+)$`

It doesn't work, I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help?

Comment: The replace string can not be a regex again. Also when you do `?f=([0-9]*)` it forces `f=` to be there, so your second URL will not match as it has `?t=6457`. And when you do `&t=[0-9]` the `[0-9]` means a single character taken from the set of 0 to 9, so in your first URL `&t=6457` won't match the regex as it has 4 characters, not one. You need `[0-9]+` to match multiple digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, with thanks to Patrick Mevzek and jpmg:

Filter type needed to be advanced, not search and replace.

Field A: `\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?(f=([0-9]+))&(t=([0-9]+))(.*)`

Field B: -

Output: `\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?$A3`

Answer (score 1):

> Search string: `\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?f=([0-9]*)&t=[0-9]`

- Replace `f` with `[a-z]` to capture any character between a and z.
- `+` to capture one or more of the parameter (`16` or `6457`, etc..) but if you know the exact length of this string you can replace it with `{1,5}` for example.
- capture everything after : `.*`

  `\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?([a-z]=([0-9]+)).*`

If you provide more urls to capture I can edit and try to adjust the regex.

Comment: What I think I understand now is that a search and replace will not work, see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742484/search-replace-request-uri-filter-in-google-analytics. I am using an advanced filter to get rid of the f=. Field A ```\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?(f=([0-9]+))(.*)```, Field B nothing, Output ```\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?$A2``` Not sure if it's going to work. If it does, I can use a second one to get rid of all that comes behind t=1234

Comment: Changed Field A to ```\/forum\/viewtopic\.php\?(f=([0-9]+))&(t=([0-9]+))(.*)```